# list.files saves files but I can not use them in the loop

Tags: r, list, loops, r-raster

I have different shapefiles and rasterfiles and I want to create a nested loop to extract the RGB values for the raster files.
I therefore save the shapefiles and raster-files in a list and then I want to read them in in the loop.

With the shapefiles it is nworking correct, but somehow the raster-files are saved in my list but I can not read them in in the loop.
The data path should be correct, because if I use the same command outside the loop it is working good.

My code is:

```
  library(rgdal)
  library(rgeos)
  library(exactextractr)
  library(sp)
  library(sf)
  library(raster)


  sites <- list.files("C:/Users/Kai/OneDrive - UT Cloud/Documents/Praktikum Mitacs/Data Files/ManualTreetops_2019_RGB/ManualTreetops_Finished",pattern = "*.shp")

  sites <- sub(".shp","",sites)

  orths <-  list.files("C:/Users/Kai/OneDrive - UT Cloud/Documents/2019_ortho",pattern="*.tif")

  orths <-  sub(".tif","",orths)

  output <- list()

  for (i.site in sites) {

    setwd("C:/Users/Kai/OneDrive - UT Cloud/Documents/Praktikum Mitacs/Data Files/ManualTreetops_2019_RGB/ManualTreetops_Finished")

    tt <- st_read(getwd(), i.site)

    crowns <- st_buffer(tt, 1)


    for(i.orth in orths) {

      setwd("C:/Users/Kai/OneDrive - UT Cloud/Documents/2019_ortho")

      oo <-  brick(getwd(),i.orth)

    crown.rgb <- exact_extract(orth,crowns,"mean")

    output[[i.site]] <- crown.rgb

    }


  } #end of for loop
```

I can also see in R-studio that the program is importing my raster files correctly into the "orths" list, but when I use the brick command it gives me the error message: "Error in .local(.Object, ...) :
Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file."
Does someone know any reason for such a problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `list.files(..., full.names=TRUE)`. Notice that `list.files` by itself only returns filenames, not the full path to get to them (when not in the working directory).

Comment: Further, `raster::brick` requires its first argument to be a filename, not a directory name. I suggest that including all of the `setwd` and `getwd` is making this script not-at-all portable or reusable without editing each time you change something, which can slow you down. If you specify the directory in one place (i.e., the `list.files(..)`) and include `full.names=TRUE`, then things tend to be safer. If you need to refer to the same directory as a full-path filename, then `dirname(.)` will give you its containing directory.

Comment: Thank you for the help, with the 'full.names = TRUE' and a change in the brick command it worked out for me!